# Can I trigger a method by any event of a certain type

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I'm building a simple windows form application. Every time the value of a control is changed the control will trigger an event that sends the new value to an object.

The thing is that I want to set a IsDirty bool to true every time that happens. I could of course write IsDirty = true in every event method, but I'm wondering if there is a slicker way of doing this - since I have tons of controls.

Could I put my IsDirty=true code in a method and make it run every time any TextChanged or ValueChanged event is triggered?

Comment: `IsDirty` is a **Data** concept, not a **UI** concept. The problem with dinosaur winforms is that you never learn to separate UI from data and thus resort to all sorts of horrible hacks. Whereas this should be resolved by adding 1 line to the `OnPropertyChanged()` method in your `Model` classes.

Comment: @HighCore - IsDirty isn't necessarily a model concept in all cases - sometimes it's a persistence concept, other times it is purely a UI concept. Which one it is in the OP's case is not clear.

Comment: Thank you HighCore. I think you just gave me an idea how to solve it! I'll just put the isdirty bool in the object receiving the data. Then set it to true when properties change. I do agree on winforms. I need to learn WPF

Comment: @lbushkin can you name 1 case where `IsDirty` will be a UI concept?

Comment: @HighCore - you have a layered compositing model that needs to track when areas of the surface have been revealed and therefore redrawn. In this case the "IsDirty" is strictly UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nice thing about events is that more than one method can be subscribed to them at a time.
You could always write a special handler:

```
private void UpdateIsDirtyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsDirty = true;
}
```

And in the Loaded event of your form, iterate over all child controls that raise a TextChanged event (TextBoxes, ComboBoxes, etc) and attach this handler to them:

```
// psuedocode:
foreach( Control ctl in myForm.Controls )
{
    if( ctl is TextBox )
    {
        ((TextBox)ctl).TextChanged += UpdateIsDirtyHandler;
    }
    if( ctl is ComboBox )  { ... }
      // etc...
}
```

If you have a set of Model objects for your form (which is a good practice in general), you could handle the "is dirty" tracking logic there. Dirty tracking is not always appropriate in your model - it depends on whether your "IsDirty" concept is something that only applies to the user interface or to the model.

Comment: Thank you! That was a great solution! The only problem I have now is that at the time the Load event triggers the form only seems to have few controls. I canät find the event "Loaded", which seems appropriate - since i'd want to iterate when the form is fully loaded. Or could it simply be because most controls are in groupboxes and tabs?

Comment: Alternatively, you can subscribe in the Activated event, but you still have to recursively explore the control tree to subscribe to all of the child controls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Changed Events as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events.aspx).
You can create a handle to this event to set the isDirty bool to be true.

I assume you have already thought about handling this isDirty bool as well and how it will be set back to false. Else it would be remain true after the first change.